# AWS DynamoDB filter not working as expected, returning 1 item instead of multiple

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

I am scanning my dynamoDB table called `organization`, and later on with that organization I am scanning for all organizations with the same `accountId`, as follows:

This is the query:

```
@Throws(GrpcInternalException::class, GrpcNotFoundException::class)
        suspend inline fun <reified T> DynamoDbTable<T>.queryIndexWithFilter(
            request: QueryConditional,
            index: String,
            startIndex: Map<String, AttributeValue>?,
            pageLimit: Int,
            streamLimit: Long,
            filterExpression: Expression,
        ): Stream<Page<T>> {
            val result = runCatching {

                val queryRequest = QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
                    .limit(pageLimit)
                    .exclusiveStartKey(startIndex)
                    .queryConditional(request)
                    .filterExpression(filterExpression)
                    .scanIndexForward(false)
                    .build()
                this.index(index).query(queryRequest).stream().limit(streamLimit)
            }.onFailure {
                Error.logAsync(it) { "EREX: ${it.message}" }
                throw GrpcInternalException(
                    "Error querying items from table ${T::class.simpleName} with partition value QueryConditional and filter expression.",
                    coroutineContext.sendAll(),
                    it,
                )
            }.getOrThrow()
            return result
        }
```

setting up and calling it with these statements:

```
val organization = organizationTable.getData(request.packageId)
        val organizationId = organization.organizationId
        val organizationIdKey = Key.builder().partitionValue(organizationId).build()

        val query = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(organizationIdKey)
        val filter = Expression.builder()
            .expression("#accountId = :val")
            .putExpressionName("#accountId", "accountId")
            .putExpressionValue(":val", AttributeValue.builder().s(organization.accountId).build())
            .build()

        val organizationsByAccount = organizationTable.queryIndexWithFilter(query,
            "Organization",
            null,
            10,
            10,
            filter
        )
```

**ACTUAL:** I am getting a Stream back containing only 1 `organization`.

**EXPECTED:** Getting all `organizations` that share the same `organization.accountId`.

I tried different functions, consulted with chatGPT where he noted that there's no issue with my query, yet arguably, DynamoDB training data would be limited (compared say to SQL), I'm not sure using a GPT here would be the ultimate solution.

Comment: You're not scanning at all, by the look of it. You're querying.

Comment: I recommend that you review the data in your table to ensure it's what you think it is and then use the awscli or DynamoDB console to make your queries and see what is returned. That will tell you whether or not your code is the problem.

Comment: @jarmod I did go over the table

Comment: Issue the queries you think are correct using awscli. Do you get the data you expect?

Comment: @jarmod I'm getting 1 item, where I have more than 1 items that have the same `accountId`

Comment: Pagination? Check if the response includes a LastEvaluatedKey, indicating that there may be more items that you will need to issue additional query requests for.

Answer (score 1):

With your request you are evaluating 100 items, based on page limit of 10 and stream limit of 10.

You set your partition key value to be "Organization"

You apply a filter expression to those 100 items, that the value for `accountId` is equal to your variable.

So out of those 100 items only 1 matched your filter, which you were returned. If you want to keep searching, then you need to paginate.